# readux-observable epics emit before firebase user is initialized

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

In my application i'm using react, redux and [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/).
I've added an epic which listens for react-router's "LOCATION_CHANGE" action and based on that payload, fires up an ajax request.

For each request, the backend expects a header which contains an apiKey.
This apiKey is something i get from firebase auth [getIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken) method.

So i wrapped my ajax calls this way:

```
function getApiKey() {
  const currentUser = window.firebase.auth().currentUser
  return from(currentUser.getIdToken()).pipe(take(1))
}

export const getJson = url =>
  getApiKey().pipe(
    filter(apiKey => apiKey),
    mergeMap(apiKey =>
      ajax.get(url, {
        apiKey
      })
    )
  )
```

The reason i need to fetch the token each time from firebase API instead of simply storing it in localstorage is because in case the key gets expired, this method will refresh it and return the new valid key.

The problem is currentUser is null for the very few milliseconds the app fires up, but the epics are trying to fetch data based on the route location before the firebase auth module is initialized so i end up having:

"Cannot find currentUser of undefined" or a similar message.

Firebase docs suggest to use "[onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)" which it's callback is invoked once the user is at available, however i do not know how to embed it in the current flow.

Assistance here is much appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, user stream will always have the last saved authorized user available

```
const user=new Observable(obs=>{
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    obs.next(user)
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    // depends what you want to do
    obs.error('unauthorized')
  }
})
}).pipe(shareReplay())

function getApiKey() {
  return user.pipe(switchMap(currentUser=>currentUser.getIdToken(),take(1))
}
```